# Infinite scroll with group_by items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement infinite scroll on a list of items (aka "Games" in my code)  following this tutorial --> http://railsforbeginners.com/chapters/chapter-9-infinite-scroll/

Here is my view :

```
<% @game_days.each do |day, games| %>

<% for game in games %>

<%= game.game_external_link %>
<%= image_tag game.photos[0].image.url(:thumb), class:"img-responsive" if game.photos.length > 0 %>
<%= game.game_name %>
<%= game.game_description %>
<%= image_tag avatar_url(game.user) %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

I've tried to refacto the code putting the code between <%= game.game_external_link %> to <%= image_tag avatar_url(game.user) %> in a partial and then putting this <%= render @games %>. But i get an infinite loop now :(

So I need help to refacto and using partial (as it says in the article).

Cheers!

Comment: for loops are almost never actually used in Ruby (at least not by people who know the language). You use `.each` if the loop is just for side effects or `.map` if you care about the return value

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/vies/games/_game.html.erb
<%= game.game_external_link %>
<%= image_tag game.photos[0].image.url(:thumb), class:"img-responsive" if game.photos.length > 0 %>
<%= game.game_name %>
<%= game.game_description %>
<%= image_tag avatar_url(game.user) %>
```

You can then render the whole collection with just:

```
<%= render games %>
```

This is shorthand for:

```
<%= render partial: 'game', collection: games %>
```

See the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) for how this works.

Comment: That what i did and i've an infinite loop with <game_days.each do |day>